# Кастомный ViewPager в Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Во многих `Android` приложениях видел виджет, который, судя по всему, был позаимствован у наших братьев iOS-ников. Виджет представляет из себя `ViewPager` с `tab-layout`, однако вместо табов в верхней части экрана, присутствуют как правило несколько кружков, которые как бы "перетекают друг в друга" при свайпе экранов. Есть ли стандартная реализация такой штуки в Android и как он называется?

Comment: например эта либа - https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: Попробуйте вот это https://github.com/chenupt/SpringIndicator

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите здесь. Может найдете то, что хотите: https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui/blob/master/pages/ViewPager.md